# Dictionary throwing StackOverflowException after ContainsKey for an object is called

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, stack-overflow

The following code is part of a heavily object orientated C# script, where I received the error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in script.exe
```

I found this to be particularly odd, since I couldn't find anything that could possibly relate to some form of process infinitely occurring within the logic of my program.

It would consistently happen as a part of `operator !=` I had made for a Coordinates class, whenever it was used as a parameter for a `Dictionary.ContainsKey()` that should have returned `true`.

This is the Coordinate Class:

```
class Coordinate
{
    private int _x;
    private int _y;
    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return _x;
        }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get
        {
            return _y;
        }
    }

    public Coordinate(Random r)
    {
        this._x = r.Next(79);
        this._y = r.Next(24);
    }

    public Coordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        this._x = x;
        this._y = y;
    }

    public static Coordinate operator +(Coordinate a, Coordinate b)
    {
        return new Coordinate(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Coordinate a, Coordinate b)
    {
        return ((a != null && b != null) && (a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y)) || (a == null && b == null);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Coordinate a, Coordinate b)
    {
        return a != null && b != null && (a.X != b.X || a.Y != b.Y) || (a == null && b != null) || (a != null && b == null);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.X.GetHashCode() * 23 + this.Y.GetHashCode() * 17;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Coordinate other = obj as Coordinate;
        return other != null && other.X == this.X && other.Y == this.Y;
    }
}
```

This is the code that would consistently cause the error, whenever the `_positions.ContainsKey(position)` should have returned `true`:

```
private bool OutOfRangeCheck(Coordinate position)
{
    return position.X < 1 || position.X > 10 || position.Y < 1 || position.Y > 10;
}

private bool PositionConflictCheck(Coordinate position)
{
    bool temp = _positions.ContainsKey(position);
    return OutOfRangeCheck(position) || _positions.ContainsKey(position);
}
```

The goal of this part of the program, was to see if a particular Coordinate had a counterpart with equal X and Y values in the dictionary shown. I found that this wouldn't work unless I had overridden the `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` methods.

If it helps, when looking at the local variables upon the error being thrown, the 'a' Coordinate in the `operator !=(Coordinate a, Coordinate b)` method, was listed as `Unable to read memory` and had a red X next to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overriding the equals operator (==) and using the equals operator in there.

```
a != null && b != null
```

If you want to compare to null, without it using your operator either cast it to an object first, like `(object)a != null` or use `object.ReferenceEquals(a, null)`.

This also applies for your not equals operator, even though it's not used by `Dictionary.ContainsKey`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I had lost sight of the fact that I was treating the parameter Coordinates like an object rather than getting their constituent parts. Thank you very much!